# Provisioning profile expired , renew without paying?

Tags: xcode

We had a company development account, and we haven't renewed it for more then a year.

We kept developing thinking we will pay later to renew it .

Now suddenly we got this :

```
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: company.C" expired on 20 Nov 2016.
```

How would you renew this without paying right now? I remember reading you can now develop on the device without paying.

Comment: Sign up for free account at apple developer account. Login with same account on xcode. In xcode  project, under team; select your personal team. In this way you can debug the app on connected devices.

Comment: Thanks very much! is there any way to do this without creating a free account? using the old one ?

Comment: No. Either use the free account or renew the old account.

Comment: Wait, but something is strange here, the program expired more then a year ago, so why now? why not a year ago?

Comment: Ok it worked, maybe you should post that as an answer, its not that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for free account at [apple developer](http://developer.apple.com) account. Login with same account on xcode (`Preference-> account`). In xcode project, under team; select your personal team. In this way you can debug the app on connected devices.